How can I use Umami analytics across subdomains?
I'm having trouble setting up Umami analytics with subdomains. Here's my scenario:
At mydomain.com, I serve my product website that advertises my service. This site includes my marketing content and ad landing pages, etc. However, serve my actual webapp over at app.mydomain.com. I want to track users across the boundary between my app and my website, so they both use the same website ID for Umami.
As far as I can tell, though, Umami doesn't differentiate between https://mydomain.com/  and https://app.mydomain.com/—they both come out as /.
I found a similar question, but it's for Google Analytics, not Umami.
I'm new to Umami and analytics in general. What am I missing here? Do I need to create a custom tracker function for this usecase, sending a custom value for url that includes the subdomain? Or is this an unsupported setup?

That's expected. Doesn't Umami have a hostname dimension? That should give you the difference

@BNazaruk Umami does track hostnames, but I can't, for example, use a funnel report to track users who use the link on mydomain.com to navigate to app.mydomain.com.
